# How to shift the baseline of an IR spectra

Tags: data-analysis

I have the fellowing IR spectra (red curve) of a sample that contains TiO2 and I would like to change the baseline in order to have a straight stable one (like the green spectra).

I wonder if its changes the other information of the spectra or not.

Does someone have an idea on how to proceed ? 
[image]
Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by change the baseline? That seems like it could not possibly report exactly the same information.

Comment: Hey ! 

Thank you for your answer. 

What I meant by "changing the baseline" is that  would like to have my baseline as a plane baseline (like the one in the green spectra). 

The purpose of this would be to normalize different spectra (all containing various TiO2 content) on the peak around 2920 cm-1 to integrate the broad peak at 1580 cm-1. 
This is not possible without modification of the baseline since this one is gradually shifted depending on the TiO2 content.

Does it help ?
Do you have any suggestion to modify the baseline ?

Thank you

Comment: I just don't understand how this could possibly work. From the mathematical point of view, it's not even clear how to label the dependent variable's axis anymore. From the chemical point of view, it's not clear that what you are subtracting off can really be attributed to one component or another. Frequently low level absorption between peaks is caused by noise or by interaction between components or other things.